# Getting error while switching from window to iframe

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver

Getting error while switching from window to iframe and getting error no iframe id found. Error is getting in testng

**Script**

```
click(locator.login_link);
```

//on clicking I get Iframe window open in few seconds

```
driver.switchTo().frame("GTM-WDM67TP");
```

//Switching to iframe window by passing id

```
click(locator.login_email);
```

//Click on element on iframe window

**Source Code**

```
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/user/main.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>

   <body class="mini-navbar">
  <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) --><noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WDM67TP" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
          <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
          <div ui-view="mainView" ng-class=""></div>
     <!-- inject:js -->
  <script src="scripts/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/vendor/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/vendor/inspiniaApp.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are the different ways for switching to the required frame:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'GTM-WDM67TP')]")));
```

Or

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-WDM67TP')]")));
```

If it is the first frame on the page, then using the index property, you can try following as well:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
```

The **id** attribute is not defined for the frame.

Comment: No this xpath is not working. Can u please suggest another way?

Comment: There can be many other ways. I have updated my answer and mentioned some options. However, if it is a publically accessible UI, could you please share the details, so that, we can find out exactly which one will work in your case?

Comment: Thanks it works now. It has been worked with index property by passing 1 and not 0, instead it has only 1 iframe present in it.